# Simple PHP script using 290Mb memory - why?

Tags: php

I have a simple PHP script running as a cron job, it's purpose is to check the headers of a webpage and report if various items have changed.

I have used various versions of this script in the past and it has always worked fine, but now I'm using it on a server that sends out warnings by email when scripts are using more than 100Mb of memory (apart from whitelisted scripts of course), and surprisingly my header-checking script is occasionally reporting large amounts of memory usage at least a few times a day.

The script is running every 5 minutes, and the memory problem is happening 5 or 6 times a day - it does seem to resolve itself, but I would like to stop it from using this large amount of memory occasionally for such a simple job.

The warning emails are reporting usage of around 290Mb for this simple script :

```
<?php

  $message = "";

  function array_find ($needle, $haystack, $search_keys = false) { 
    if (!is_array($haystack)) return false;
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
      $what = ($search_keys) ? $key : $value;
      if (strpos($what, $needle) !== false) return $key;
    }
    return false;
  }

  $url = 'http://www.EXAMPLE.com/';

  $haystack = get_headers($url);
  $needle = "PHPSESSID";

  if (!((array_find($needle, $haystack)) != '')) {
    $message .= "No PHPSESSID in headers";
  }

  if (!(strpos($haystack[0], '200'))) {
    $message .= "No 200 OK";
  }

  if ($message != '') {
    mail("example@example.com", "Headers Changed", $message, "From: Example <example@example.com>");
  }

  exit;

?>
```

The server is a VPS running CENTOS 5.8, Apache 2.2.16, PHP 5.3.3

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Would you consider making your code a bit more readable by using newlines? I'm positive there's no need for a function to go on a single line. It probably helps with people wanting to take the time to look at your code.

Comment: `if (!((array_find($needle, $haystack))!='')) {`? Really? Why not just `if (array_find($needle, $haystack) === FALSE)`?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're just getting large haystacks 5 or 6 times a day?

PHP is a memory-hungry beast. That's a fact. When dealing with relatively large arrays of data the memory consumption can become more than just noticeable.

There's an interesting article on that, named ["How big are PHP arrays (and values)? (Hint: BIG!)"](http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html) A highly recommended read!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try doing memory_get_usage() after each major part. That should help you narrow it down.

Answer (score 1):

Try making a file with only get_headers($url) and memory_get_usage() and see the results...

```
<?php 
$url = "http://www.example.com";
get_headers($url);
echo memory_get_usage();
?>
```

In my experience get_headers() on PHP >= 5 eats a lot of memory. You can check the article "[get_headers() function results in memory leak](http://awordpress.net/blog/get_headers%28%29-function-memory-leak/)"

PS:You can also use xDebug to trace the memory usage of the script